# Dice probability

Tags: c++, math, dice

I am trying to work out how to make a dice rolling application display a percentage chance for each result.  For example a single six sided dice would display: 1 = 16.6% 2 = 16.6% 3 = 16.6% 4= 16.6% 5 = 16.6% 6 = 16.6%.

The user will input the type of dice (number of sides n) and the number of dice to be rolled (d).

Has anyone got a formula that would work for C++? I just can't seem to work it out/understand what I have been able to find so far.

Thanks

**EDIT** I would like to store the results in an array of some sort as well if that is possible

Comment: did you want each die to be able to have a different number of sides?

Comment: Yes each dice can either be 4, 6, 8, 10 or 20 sides

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#Probability

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths/probability, not programming.

Comment: Dont forget strength stat modifiers if dice is for melee weapons. And multiply with 1.5 if two handed sword.

Comment: For the die 6 example, it's simply:
`cout << 100 / n >> "% chance for each of the " << n << " sides.";
If you want to handle multiple roles of different dice, probability of each roll's results are independent of all other rolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void dice_analysis(int dice_sides, int dice_number, float * h2, int precision)
{
     int temp=0;
     int histogram[dice_sides*dice_number];
     //init histogram
     for(int k=0;k<dice_sides*dice_number;k++)
     {
          histogram[k]=0;
     }
     //statistical analysis
     for(int i=0;i<precision;i++)
     {
          temp=0;
          for(int j=0;j<dice_number;j++)
          {

               temp+=( rand()%dice_sides +1 );
          }
          for(int k=0;k<dice_sides*dice_number;k++)
          {
               if(temp==(k+1)){histogram[k]++;}
               //actually histogram[temp]++; look better
          }


     }
     //printing the calculated results
     for(int k=0;k<dice_sides*dice_number;k++)
     {
               cout<<k+1<<":"<<(float)histogram[k]/(precision/100.0f)<<"%"<<endl;
               h2[k]=histogram[k]/(precision/100.0f);
     }


}
```

Output for dice_analysis(8,2,x,1000) ---> two 8 sided dices

```
1:0%
2:1.5%
3:4.4%
4:3.8%
5:5.7%
6:8.8%
7:9.1%
8:10.2%
9:14%
10:10.2%
11:8.3%
12:7.5%
13:6.8%
14:6%
15:2.8%
16:0.9%
```

You can see that "1" is not possible for two or more dices. Also "9" is most probable by being %14 chance.

You can use like: `dice_analysis(8,2,output_array,1000);`

Comment: this seem perfect apart from when i try with 1 6 sided dice.  all the answers are a little different when surely it should all be 16.7%?

Comment: If you need precision, increase from 1000 to 100000 and divide histograms by 1000 instead of 1000. I added the array-output version.

Comment: Added customizable precision version.

Comment: Changed output array from int to float to get less than 1 percents.

Comment: This was a version of my "boss vs hero win-win probability" function.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<double> probas;
for(i = 1; i <= num_faces; ++i)
{
    std::cout << i << " = " << 100.0 / num_faces << "%" << std::endl;
    probas.push_back(100.0 / num_faces);
}
```

Edit for vector stuff

Comment: however I didn't take into account that your players have a 70% increased chance of critical against last boss